# j5 cant open after updating to marshemallow

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j5

j5 cant open after updating to marshemallow and it display the word (samsung) in the screen for 20 hours without opening

tried restarting and removed the battery and the same happens

Comment: its the ROM from samsung they asked me to update an i did it .. i cant even do it myself

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache memory by booting to recovery? I have the same phone and had not issue when I upgr to Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly happens when an incompatible ROM or KERNEL is installed on the phone. It is known as boot-loop, the phone never leaves the booting screen. To fix this issue in most cases, you have to change to a different ROM or KERNEL.
In your case it is the problem with the ROM as you mentioned that you updated to Marshmallow. It happens mostly when you try to update it yourself and not from OTA updates, if you really did update it yourself just flash a different ROM insuring that ROM is compatible with your device model.

Comment: its the ROM from samsung they asked me to update an i did it .. i cant even do it myself

Comment: You could try wiping cache and delvik cache, if still not solved then flash a previous ROM for that model.

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue with Samsung Marshmallow update. I too had the same problem a couple of months ago.

The easiest way to get it done is to reach **Samsung Care** asap. They will hardly take your five minutes to fix it.

One of my friend tried installing stock Marshmallow ROM with ODIN and ended up with a bricked device.

So the easiest and safest way possible is to visit Samsung Care asap.